# Passing an object as an argument to a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, struct

I have this simple program that gets the two lines (objects) with their coefficients, and returns 2 if they cross each other, 1 if they are parallel, and 0 if they are the same line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct line {
        float a;
        float b;
    } line1, line2;

int lineRelation = (line line1, line line2) {
  int answer = 2;
  yIntercept1 = line1.b;
  yIntercept2 = line2.b;
  if (yIntercept1 == yIntercept2 && line1.a == line2.a) {
      answer = 0;
  } else if (line1.a == line2.a) {
      answer = 1;
  }
  return answer;
};

int main() {
    
    // y = ax + b
    line1.a = 4; line1.b = 3;
    line2.a = 8; line2.b = 6;
    cout<<lineRelation(line1, line2)<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I want to compile the program, I get the following errors:

```
g++ /tmp/y3g4MgJxUy.cpp
/tmp/y3g4MgJxUy.cpp:10:26: error: expected primary-expression before 'line1'
   10 | int lineRelation = (line line1, line line2) {
      |                          ^~~~~
/tmp/y3g4MgJxUy.cpp:10:25: error: expected ')' before 'line1'
   10 | int lineRelation = (line line1, line line2) {
      |                    ~    ^~~~~~
      |                         )
/tmp/y3g4MgJxUy.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/tmp/y3g4MgJxUy.cpp:26:36: error: 'lineRelation' cannot be used as a function
   26 |     cout<<lineRelation(line1, line2)<<endl;
      |                                    ^
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Avoid global variable like that, especially when you have parameter of the same names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't declare your function correctly:

```
int lineRelation = (line line1, line line2) {
```

That's not the right way to declare a function. Look at `main` as a viable example.

While we're at it, make sure to pass your objects by reference for efficiency. Else the code makes a needless temp copy.

Better:

```
int lineRelation(const line& line1, const line& line2) {
  int answer = 2;
  yIntercept1 = line1.b;
  yIntercept2 = line2.b;
  if (yIntercept1 == yIntercept2 && line1.a == line2.a) {
      answer = 0;
  } else if (line1.a == line2.a) {
      answer = 1;
  }
  return answer;
};
```

Comment: For small trivial objects, it is debatable for the best ways to pass arguments. By value might go directly in register whereas by const ref might incurs extra redirection.